# Having problem with showing Login Pop-up dialog with Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I'm using AWS Amplify, React and Facebook SDK to let users sign in. It seems to work but the pop up shows and closes right away.

I have tried this code, FB.init and FB.getLoginStatus and FB.login

```
statusChangeCallback = response => {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
      this.handleResponse(response.authResponse);
    } else {
      this.handleError(response);
    }
  };

  checkLoginState = () => {
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(this.statusChangeCallback);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    window.FB.login(this.checkLoginState, {scope: "public_profile,email"});
  };

  handleError(error) {
    alert(error);
  }

  async handleResponse(data) {
    const { email, accessToken: token, expiresIn } = data;
    const expires_at = expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
    const user = { email };

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    try {
      const response = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
        "facebook",
        { token, expires_at },
        user
      );
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    console.log(response)
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      this.handleError(e);
    }
  }
```

I want the pop up dialog to show up and allow users to allow my app to access their credentials from FB.

---

EDIT

I figured it out by having a Sign out button, logging out with AWS Auth and deauthorizing FB with this code:

```
signOut () {
  Auth.signOut({ global: true })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  window.FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", function(response){});
}
```

After signing in again, I finally got to click the Continue button and authorize my app!

Thanks for all the help

Comment: _“but the pop up shows and closes right away”_ - you’re aware that’s how it is _supposed_ to work, if the user has already authorized the app before, right? Is that your case, or did it do that on the very first try already, so that you are _not_ logged in and have _not_ granted the requested permissions afterwards?

Comment: I never had the chance to authorize the app by clicking a **Continue** button

Comment: How exactly is `handleClick` called? Does that happen directly on user interaction (click), not wrapped into any async callbacks or anything like that? (If it is not called directly on the user interaction, the popup blocker might eat the login popup.)

Comment: side note: shouldn´t "handleResponse" be an arrow function, since you are accessing "this"?

Comment: @04FS Yes `handleClick` is called through click of a button. Popup shows with no content but only for a sec and then goes away

Comment: Do you get any response logged in console from your callback function then?

Comment: Yes the `CognitoIdentityCredentials`